# Identify program that connects to a Unix Domain Socket

Tags: linux, unix-socket

I have a program that is listening to a Unix Domain Socket.

When a client connects to the socket I'd like to find out which program connected and then decide if I allow the connection or not (based on the user/group settings).

Is this possible under Linux, and if so, how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this is possible on Linux, but it won't be very portable. It's achieved using what is called "ancillary data" with `sendmsg` / `recvmsg`.

- Use `SO_PASSCRED` with `setsockopt`
- Use `SCM_CREDENTIALS` and the `struct ucred` structure

This structure is defined in Linux:

```
struct ucred {
    pid_t pid;    /* process ID of the sending process */
    uid_t uid;    /* user ID of the sending process */
    gid_t gid;    /* group ID of the sending process */
};
```

Note you have to fill these in your `msghdr.control`, and the kernel will check if they're correct.

The main portability hindrance is that this structure differs on other Unixes - for example on FreeBSD it's:

```
struct cmsgcred {
    pid_t   cmcred_pid;          /* PID of sending process */
    uid_t   cmcred_uid;          /* real UID of sending process */
    uid_t   cmcred_euid;         /* effective UID of sending process */
    gid_t   cmcred_gid;          /* real GID of sending process */
    short   cmcred_ngroups;      /* number or groups */
    gid_t   cmcred_groups[CMGROUP_MAX];     /* groups */
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for. Portability is not an issue. The code will only run on Android as native code anyway.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to the socket. I'm wondering how can I know the PID of the sending process. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I searched for this quite a bit, so I will show you this example on how to use `SO_PEERCRED` on a socket `sock` to get the pid/uid/gid of the peer of a socket:

```
int len;
struct ucred ucred;

len = sizeof(struct ucred);

if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, &ucred, &len) == -1) {
    //getsockopt failed
}

printf("Credentials from SO_PEERCRED: pid=%ld, euid=%ld, egid=%ld\n",
    (long) ucred.pid, (long) ucred.uid, (long) ucred.gid);
```

Comment: I also searched quite a lot, and feel very lucky to have found this answer! Most other sources insist that you need to use `sendmsg` and `recvmsg` when this is simply untrue.

I'll add that the `sock` parameter in the example given would be the file descriptor of the client process you want to identify, and I found I needed to do at least one `read()` of data from the client, otherwise I got undefined values in the `ucred` struct.

Comment: glibc since 2.8.0 (2009) requires `_GNU_SOURCE` to be defined. Ad-hoc source: https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/2860

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [getpeername](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpeername) or [getsockname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockname) could help. and I think that the permission of your [unix socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) are useful (not sure of that). And you might read the link inside `/proc/self/fd/12` if your `accept`-ed socket is 12.

**EDIT**

using ancillary data for credentials and `sendmsg` is much better, as suggested by *cnicutar* below.